# OpenRefine text transform delete all characters from character "["

Tags: text, transform, openrefine

I want to delete all characters after the "[" character like the screenshot below:

[Schreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYXh0.png)

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Input examples from the provided screenshot:

- 189 [122-270]
- 18 [5.10-6.90]

The easiest way would be to split the column on the separator `[` and delete the second column.

The more elaborate way would be to use a regular expression:

`value.replace(/\s\[[^\]]+\]/, "")`

Play around with https://regex101.com/ or https://regexr.com/ to find out more about how this regular expression works.

Comment: It works! thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip regex complexity, I will use the split function `value.split('[')[0]`
The split() function create an array, and the `[0]` selector pick the first value of the array.